# WPF waiting for the UI to finish

Tags: wpf, user-interface, thread-safety

I have a code that needs to refresh the UI then wait for it to finish (refreshing may involve animations) and then keep going. Is there a way to call the `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action (()=> { PerformUpdateWithAnimations(); }` in a syncrhonous way?

This is the overall look:

```
List<thingsThatMove> myThings = new List<ThingsThatMove>();

//normal code interacting with the data
// let's name this part of code A
foreach (thing t in myThings) 
{ 
    thing.currentPosition = SomePoint;
    if(thing.wasRejectedBySystem) thing.needsToMove = true;
}



//As a result of A we have some impact in the UI
//That may need some animations (let's call this bloc B)
 Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { 
     foreach(thing in myThings)
         if(thing.needsToMove)
              createNewAnimation(thing);
 }));

 //Here is some final code that needs the final position of some
 //of the elements, so it cannot be executed until the B part has
 // been finished. Let's call this bloc C

 updateInternalValues(myThings);
 cleanUp();
```

I tried encapsulating B into a BackgroundWoker. Setting the B bloc as the `DoWork` and listening to the `completed` but it doent work since the B blok "completes" after the Application.Current.Dispatcher is called, not after the dispatcher itself finishes everything

How can I make C wait until all the animations in B are finished ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use async/await to call asynchrnously and continue after it has been executed..

```
private async void RefreshCode()
{
    List<thingsThatMove> myThings = new List<ThingsThatMove>();

    //normal code interacting with the data
    // let's name this part of code A
    foreach (thing t in myThings) 
    { 
        thing.currentPosition = SomePoint;
        if(thing.wasRejectedBySystem) thing.needsToMove = true;
    }

    //As a result of A we have some impact in the UI
    //That may need some animations (let's call this bloc B)
    await Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(new Action(() => { 
         foreach(thing in myThings)
             if(thing.needsToMove)
                  createNewAnimation(thing);
     }));

     //Here is some final code that needs the final position of some
     //of the elements, so it cannot be executed until the B part has
     // been finished. Let's call this bloc C

     updateInternalValues(myThings);
     cleanUp();
}
```

Comment: if it starts a delegate Asyncrhonously ... won't my code keep on going without waiting for it to finish ? I need to wait for it to finish before keeping on

Comment: Is there a way to add UI level to the Task ?? because inside my PerformUpdateWithAnimations I have a call to Application.dispatcher.invoke

Comment: I would need to see more code. Post examples of what you have

Comment: I did a major update in the question with plenty of pseudocode to clarify the problem.